# Rails edit form not showing nested item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I got a form that have a nested link. The problem that the link field is empty on edit.
Here is my form:

```
<h1>Editing kategori</h1>
<%= simple_form_for(@konkurrancer, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @konkurrancer.id }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :link_attributes do |d| %>
    <%= d.input :link, :label => 'Tracking url', :style => 'width:500;' %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.button :submit, :value => 'Edit konkurrence' %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Show', admin_konkurrancer_path %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', admin_konkurrancer_path %>
```

My konkurrencer model:

```
has_one :link
```

My link model:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :konkurrancer
accepts_nested_attributes_for :konkurrancer
end
```

My konkurrancer edit action:

```
  def edit
    @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.find(params[:id])
    @konkurrancer.link_attributes.build
  end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Remove from your Link model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :konkurrancer
```

and add to your Konkurrancer model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :link
```

2) In controller edit action remove

```
@konkurrancer.link_attributes.build
```

and in controller new action add

```
@konkurrances.build_link
```

3) In the view file replace

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :link_attributes do |d| %>
```

with

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :link do |d| %>
```

Comment: Please provide the sources of your Konkurrancer model and controller with edit action.

Comment: In the `edit` action I would not do the `build_link`, only in the `new` action.

Comment: @nathanvda true, forgot about has_one relation